# cell height as image height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

Hi There I'm trying to let the cell height as image height

I'm using PinterestLayout, every thing work fine but the problem is the heightForPhotoAtIndexPath return before getting the height of images

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        // Get  Object

        let images = addArray[indexPath.row]["images"] as! [PFFile]
        let image = images[0] as PFFile
        image.getDataInBackground(block: { (data, error) in
            if error == nil { if let imageData = data {
                self.image2 = UIImage(data: imageData)!
                self.height = self.image2.size.height
                if self.height > 1000.0 {
                    self.height = self.height / 4.0
                } else if self.height > 450 {
                    self.height = self.height / 3.0
                }
                print(self.height)
                }}})

        print(height)
        return height

       }
```

> ```
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 281.0
> 609.0
> 250.0
> 197.666666666667
> 281.0
> 281.0
> 281.0
> 281.0
> 281.0
> ```

Comment: I would suggest not to do this kind of fetch in a `collectionview` delegate method, rather make this call in different method and store the heights in some structure(e.g in an array) and then use those heights to do the work you want to do above.

Comment: like this method ?  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return cellSize
    }

Comment: If the image is downloaded asynchronously, then you can't know in advance what size it has, so your best approach would be to estimate the size, and invalidate the layout of the collection view cell once the download has finished. However that might not result in the best experience. Alternatively, if the server supports it, you could request the image with the size you need.

Answer (score 0):

In my previous project I used Pinterest Layout and I did this method in below. But I dont remember the details.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let itemSize = (collectionView.frame.width - (collectionView.contentInset.left + collectionView.contentInset.right + 10)) / 2
    return CGSize(width: itemSize, height: itemSize)
}
```